# module layout file seems to be ignored

Tags: magento, controller

I have a simple module and an IndexController which outputs my custom logic.I create a layout for that module and but it doesn't works or or any thisng missing by me.Can someone point me to a right direction or where i made mistake in `config.xml`.

Here is my `config.xml`

```
<config>
    <global>
        <modules>
            <Namespace_Testmodule>
                <version>1.0.1</version>
            </Namespace_Testmodule>
        </modules>
        <frontend>
            <routers>
                <Namespace_Testmodule>
                    <use>standard</use>
                    <args>
                        <module>Namespace_Testmodule</module>
                        <frontName>test</frontName>
                    </args>
                </Namespace_Testmodule>
            </routers>
            <layout>
                <updates>
                    <Namespace_Testmodule>
                        <file>Namespace_Testmodule.xml</file>
                    </Namespace_Testmodule>
                </updates>
            </layout>
        </frontend>

        <models>
            <testmodule>
                <class>Namespace_Testmodule_Model</class>
            </testmodule>
        </models>


        <resources>

            <Namespace_Testmodule_setup>

                <setup>

                    <module>Namespace_Testmodule</module>
                </setup>

                <connection>

                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </Namespace_Testmodule_setup>
            <Namespace_Testmodule_write>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </Namespace_Testmodule_write>
            <Namespace_Testmodule_read>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </Namespace_Testmodule_read>
        </resources>
        <blocks>
            <testmodule>
                <class>Namespace_Testmodule_Block</class>      
            </testmodule>
        </blocks>

        <helpers>
            <codchecker>
                <class>Namespace_Testmodule_Helper</class>
            </codchecker>
        </helpers>


    </global>



     </config>
```

When i run my url like localhost/magento/index.php/test/index it gives me 404 page

What am I missing? Any help will be appreciated

Thank you

Comment: How looks your directory structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keyur, routers should be define outside in global tag

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <config>
    <global>
        <modules>
            <Namespace_Testmodule>
                <version>1.0.1</version>
            </Namespace_Testmodule>
        </modules>
</global>
  <frontend>
            <routers>
                <testmodule>
                    <use>standard</use>
                    <args>
                        <module>Namespace_Testmodule</module>
                        <frontName>test</frontName>
                    </args>
                </testmodule>
            </routers>
            <layout>
                <updates>
                    <testmodule>
                        <file>testmodule.xml</file>
                    </testmodule>
                </updates>
            </layout>
        </frontend>
    <global>
    <models>
            <testmodule>
                <class>[Namespace]_[Module]_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>testmodule_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </testmodule>
            <testmodule_mysql4>
                <class>Namespace_Testmodule_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <testmodule>
                        <table>testmodule</table>
                    </testmodule]>
                </entities>
            </testmodule_mysql4>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <testmodule]_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Namespace_Testmodule</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </testmodule_setup>
            <testmodule_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </testmodule_write>
            <testmodule_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </testmodule_read>
        </resources>
    <blocks>
            <testmodule>
                <class>Namespace_Testmodule_Block</class>      
            </testmodule>
        </blocks>

        <helpers>
            <codchecker>
                <class>Namespace_Testmodule_Helper</class>
            </codchecker>
        </helpers>


    </global>
    </config>
```

import note for helper class please call a`lways Mage::helper("codchecker") as you define helper init is codchecker`

Comment: Thanks @Amit for point out me to my sillay mistake +1 for you